# How to plot four independent variables in just one plot (scatterplot) in R

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

Is it possible to plot 4 independent variables in just one scatterplot (or different type of plot) in R? I would like to get a one scatterplot/plot showing correlation between the three spectral indicies (NDVI, NDBI and NDWI) and Land Surface Temperature (LST). I am working with ascii text files representing raster data for these four variables. I have created separate graphs so far (see Fig. 1 and code), but I would like to have all three spectral indices together in just one plot with LST to show the synergy between spectral indices (and LST).

[Fig. 1 Scatter plots showing correlations between spectral indices and LST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkzI9.jpg)

````
setwd("C:/scatterplot//4variables")
getwd()

library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(fields)

# importing raster layers

grid.lst <- readGDAL("lst_raster.txt")
grid.ndvi <- readGDAL("ndvi_raster.txt")
grid.ndbi <- readGDAL("ndbi_raster.txt")
grid.ndwi <- readGDAL("ndwi_raster.txt")

# putting all raster values into a table / data frame

temp.df <- as.data.frame(cbind(grid.lst@data, grid.ndvi@data, grid.ndbi@data, grid.ndwi@data))
head(temp.df)
names(temp.df) <- c("lst", "ndvi", "ndbi", "ndwi")

# linear regression of LST vs 3 independent variables/predictors
lm.output.lst <- lm(lst ~ ndvi + ndbi + ndwi, setwd)
summary(lm.output)

# drawing scatterplots for bivariate regressions of LST with NDVI, NDBI, NDWI

# setting colour scheme for legend 
Lab.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "#00FEFF", "#45FE4F", 
                            "#FCFF00", "#FF9400", "#FF3100"), space = "Lab")

# creating a function to save the results of linear regression
lm_eqn <- function(df){
    m <- lm(y  ~ x, df);
    eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(R)^2~"="~r2, 
         list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2), 
              b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2), 
             r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)));                 
}

legend.f <- function(){
  xm <- get('xm', envir = parent.frame(1))
  ym <- get('ym', envir = parent.frame(1))
  z  <- get('dens', envir = parent.frame(1))
  colramp <- get('colramp', parent.frame(1))
  fields::image.plot(xm,ym,z, col = colramp(256),
          legend.args=list( text="PDF", cex=0.8, side=3, line=0.7), 
        legend.only = T, legend.width=3, add =F)
}

# openning a graphic window with 3 subwindows
par(mfrow = c(1, 3), mar=.1+c(3,4,4,6), mgp = c(1.5, 0.5, 0))

# --------- NDVI x LST ---------
# merging two variables into one table for linear regression
## head(temp.df)

# draw graph/plot
temp.df.xy <- temp.df[,c("ndvi", "lst")]
names(temp.df.xy) <- c("x","y")
smoothScatter(temp.df.xy, nrpoints = 0, 
    colramp=Lab.palette, postPlotHook = legend.f, 
    xlab="NDVI", ylab="LST")
title(" ", line=2)
mtext(lm_eqn(temp.df.xy), 3, line=0, cex=0.8, col="red")

## add regression line to the plot
abline(lm(y  ~ x, temp.df.xy), col="red", lt=2)

# --------- NDBI x LST ---------
# merging two variables into one table for linear regression
## head(temp.df)

# draw graph/plot
temp.df.xy <- temp.df[,c("ndbi", "lst")]
names(temp.df.xy) <- c("x","y")
smoothScatter(temp.df.xy, nrpoints = 0, 
    colramp=Lab.palette, postPlotHook = legend.f, 
    xlab="NDBI", ylab="LST")
title(" ", line=2)
mtext(lm_eqn(temp.df.xy), 3, line=0, cex=0.8, col="red")

## add regression line to the plot
abline(lm(y  ~ x, temp.df.xy), col="red", lt=2)

# --------- NDWI x LST ---------
# merging two variables into one table for linear regression
## head(temp.df)

# draw graph/plot
temp.df.xy <- temp.df[,c("ndwi", "lst")]
names(temp.df.xy) <- c("x","y")
smoothScatter(temp.df.xy, nrpoints = 0, 
    colramp=Lab.palette, postPlotHook = legend.f, 
    xlab="NDWI", ylab="LST")
title(" ", line=2)
mtext(lm_eqn(temp.df.xy), 3, line=0, cex=0.8, col="red")

## add regression line to the plot
abline(lm(y  ~ x, temp.df.xy), col="red", lt=2) ```
````

Comment: Conceptually, a scatter plot has 2 axes, each of which represent a variable. If there's a 3rd concurrent variable we can use color to visualize it--your plots use color to represent the density of points. I don't know of any good ways to introduce additional continuous variables into the same plot. Do you have ideas or examples of what you're looking for?

Comment: I´m quite new to R, but what we want to get in the form of the 1 scatterplot/plot for all variables together is basically this console output: `Call: lm(formula = lst ~ ndvi + ndbi + ndwi, data = temp.df)` where we get in the console output in R coefficients like Multiple R-squared: 0.80. If it is possible to visualise this output using colors to represent the density of points for three indices (NDVI, NDWI, NDBI) vs. LST in just one plot with  regression line and regression coefficient for all of these four variables it would be ideal

Comment: Okay, I think that's a little more helpful. Could you share some sample data so that we have something to work with? Something like `dput(temp.df[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows, or else code to simulate fake data if you'd rather the example be at scale.

Comment: We can try to use transparency, but if there are points on top of each other from all 3 variables, I think it will just look like a confusing mess.

Comment: I am sorry, not sure how to make these fake data or how to write it in lines; since I have been working only with raster data an I am also new to programming... something like this? I can send the original raster data in ascii format if it will be more helpful.


```dput(temp.df[1:10, 2:4, 4:6, 6:8], [2:9, 3:6, 5:7, 6:9], [6:1, 2:8, 4:5, 3:1], [7:3, 5:4, 10:2, 10:1], [5:10, 6:4, 9:8, 7:5], [5:1, 5:4, 4:5, 5:8], [9:10, 5:1, 5:6, 5:8], [6:2, 8:4, 10:6, 9:8], [2:9, 3:4, 7:6, 8:8], [3:3, 7:4, 1:7, 5:2])```

Comment: Yes, we can try to test it using transparency and see if it will be readable

Comment: I need the output from the `dput()`. If you run the `dput` command it will make a copy/pasteable version of the R object. I don't need the raster objects, just a sample of the data frame you make. Run the command `dput(temp.df[1:10, ])` in your R console, and edit your question to include the output. (Please don't put it in comments where it is hard to read and it might be too long for a comment.)